# How do I remove unwanted white border around images?

Tags: html, css

While making a carousel of images on a dark background, I keep facing the issue of mysterious white borders around the images on specific browsers.

[image: screenshot]

I have tried setting the box-shadow to 0, removing borders, and adding borders in the color of the image-background; but none of these trials have resulted in a change.

The current CSS:

```
.card-carousel-cell img {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #252525;
    display: block;
}
```

Is there any way I can remove this issue consistently across browsers?

Comment: Are you using Owl Carousel?

Comment: Could you please add a code example of these border images? This would make finding a solution much easier.

Comment: @CaddyDZ I am using Flickity, but I have seen this issue even without using any libraries.

Comment: @DaanSeuntjens I added all the image styling within the question, there is no other code that affects the img tag

Comment: I'm missing some html or such to check these outputs in different browsers, we can't test out your code like this.

Comment: For sure remove whitespace around the image tag `<a href=""><img /></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the image in a div with transparent background. `.img-container` is the div with transparent background and `.myimg` is the image. [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/eLnh2rd4/2/).

```
.img-container {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.myimg {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```